# Adding a same value to each channel in a 3 channel image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I read an image :

```
img = cv2.imread("sky.png", 1)
```

Now, I want to add one pixel in each column for each channel. The way I attempted this is as follows:

```
img[row_1, :, 0] = np.insert(img[row_1,:,0], column_1, some_value)
img[row_1, :, 1] = np.insert(img[row_1,:,1], column_1, some_value)
img[row_1, :, 2] = np.insert(img[row_1,:,2], column_1, some_value)
```

Is there a better way of doing this, than to write to each channel separately?

**UPDATE**:
As I have mentioned, that I want to add a new **column**, that is a 4x4 image, gets transformed to 4x5 image. The value of each pixel is different and the order of columns is also not fixed. For example, first pixel gets inserted into 3 column and second pixel gets inserted into 1 column and so on (using a predetermined set of columns)

Example:

```
[
  [1,2,3,4],
  [4,5,6,7],
  [8,9,10,11]
]
```

The above is a 3x4 image (will be a 3 channel image, in reality). I want to convert this to 3x5 image by adding pixels at [0,2] , [1,1], [2,4]

The output then becomes:

```
[
   [1,2, new-pixel-a, 3, 4],
   [4,new-pixel-b, 5, 6, 7]
   [8, 9, 10, 11, new-pixel-c]
]
```

So I get a new image, (3, 5)

Comment: check [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/14052/resize-an-image-but-fill-the-space-with-black/) out, maybe it helps. Let me know.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Could not understand. Would you know an example with OpenCV and numpy?

Comment: Do you mean the image height should increase by 1?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes. But I want to insert different pixels for each row. For a 4x4 image, that will be 5x4, I want to insert 5 different pixels.

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing both Hans and me. Maybe you could show a small, plain image to start with and how it should look afterwards? Along with before and after dimensions. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Have added an example

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? Maybe you could just resize the image 1px wider and then overwrite your desired locations with new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation on NumPy's [`insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) method, I would come up with the following solution:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image; output image dimensions
image = cv2.imread('N8e9S.png')
print(image.shape)

# Set up column indices where to add pixels
colIdx = np.array(image.shape[0] * np.random.rand(image.shape[0]), dtype=np.int32)

# Set up pixel values to add
pixels = np.uint8(255 * np.random.rand(image.shape[0], 3))

# Initialize separate image
newImage = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]+1, 3), np.uint8)

# Insert pixels at predefined locations
for i in range(colIdx.shape[0]):
    newImage[i, :, :] = np.insert(image[i, :, :], colIdx[i], pixels[i, :], axis=0)

# Output (new) image dimensions
print(newImage.shape)

# Show final image
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('newImage', newImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image is this one:

[image: Input]

The final output looks like this:

[image: Output]

Print output to verify new image dimensions:

```
(241, 300, 3)
(241, 301, 3)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I need to insert different pixels in each row. This will insert same pixel value to each row

Comment: @Amanda That's how I understood your question. I've edited my answer to insert a whole row, here with some randomly generated pixels.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am trying to insert a new column where the order of columns is not fixed. While one new pixel is inserted each column, order could vary (as determined by pre-calculated set). For example, one pixel could go to (1,19), second could go at (2, 1) etc. In essence, one new column will be added.

Comment: Also added a small example

Comment: @Amanda Another update of my answer. I hope, I now got your idea. Nevertheless, now I can't see any solution without using an additional `newImage` with column size + 1, and looping over all pixels, since you have varying column indices. At least the `np.insert` call could by simplified.